# “Read more” toggle not with amount of character but sentence length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I’m creating “read more” and “read less” buttons. However, right now it is showing only 100 character because I have set it like this `var showChar = 100;`. I don’t want to decide by characters length but sentence length. There will be several articles I will be adding and I want each article to have a different length at the beginning. Is there some way to do this? Have been trying to figure it out and I am beginner in this.

Here is example how would like to have it.

Here is my article:

> In reaction to Russian Prime Minister Dmitry Medvedev’s visit to Etorofu Island on Saturday, the government will stop making arrangements for Foreign Minister Fumio Kishida to visit Russia for the time being, government sources said... more

I want it to break at the point where it says “more”.

> The move comes after the government felt strong resentment over the Russian prime minister’s visit to Etorofu, one of the four northern territories off Hokkaido.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showChar = 100;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "more";
    var lesstext = "less";
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
 
        if(content.length > showChar) {
 
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
 
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
 
            $(this).html(html);
        }
 
    });
 
    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
a {
    color: #4088ff;
}
a:visited {
    color: #4088ff;
}
a.morelink {
    text-decoration:none;
    outline: none;
}
.morecontent span {
    display: none;
}
.comment more{

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment more">
 <h2> Home</h2>
    In reaction to Russian Prime Minister Dmitry Medvedev’s visit to Etorofu Island on Saturday, the government will stop making arrangements for Foreign Minister Fumio Kishida to visit Russia for the time being, government sources said.

The move comes after the government felt strong resentment over the Russian prime minister’s visit to Etorofu, one of the four northern territories off Hokkaido.

<br><br>
     <ul>
      <li> Text text kdfjlsdjflksjdflkjsldjfs</li>
     <li>Text text kdfjlsdjflksjdflkjsldjfs</li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered adding a `<!-- break -->` comment in the article, locating the comment and using that as character length? (Drupal does this.)

Comment: Can you please explain more? I did not quite understand it.

Comment: I’m posting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left `showChar` undefined at first, then searched the HTML comment `<!-- break -->` and used that as `showChar`. This way you have full control over where exactly the break point is set. Just insert `<!-- break -->` in your article wherever you need it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ellipsestext = "...",
    moretext = "more",
    lesstext = "less",
    showChar;
  $('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    showChar = content.search(/<!\-\-\s*break\s*\-\->/);
    if (content.length > showChar && showChar != -1) {

      var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
      var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

      var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

      $(this).html(html);
    }

  });

  $(".morelink").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
      $(this).removeClass("less");
      $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("less");
      $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #4088ff;
}
a:visited {
  color: #4088ff;
}
a.morelink {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
.morecontent span {
  display: none;
}
.comment more {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment more">
  <h2> Home</h2>
  In reaction to Russian Prime Minister Dmitry Medvedev’s visit to Etorofu Island on Saturday, the government will stop making arrangements for Foreign Minister Fumio Kishida to visit Russia<!-- break --> for the time being, government sources said.

  The move comes after the government felt strong resentment over the Russian prime minister’s visit to Etorofu, one of the four northern territories off Hokkaido.

  <br>
  <br>
  <ul>
    <li>Text text kdfjlsdjflksjdflkjsldjfs</li>
    <li>Text text kdfjlsdjflksjdflkjsldjfs</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! That is exactly what I was trying to figure it out.To be able to have full control over where exactly the break point is set. Thank you very much! Now its working!

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of `showChar` using the position of end of first sentence using `var showChar = content.indexOf(".") + 1;` this is calculated for each time loop executes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //var showChar = 100;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "more";
    var lesstext = "less";
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
        var showChar = content.indexOf(".") + 1;
        if(content.length > showChar) {
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
            $(this).html(html);
        }
    });
 
    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
a {
    color: #4088ff;
}
a:visited {
    color: #4088ff;
}
a.morelink {
    text-decoration:none;
    outline: none;
}
.morecontent span {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment more">
 <h2> Home</h2>
    In reaction to Russian Prime Minister Dmitry Medvedev’s visit to Etorofu Island on Saturday, the government will stop making arrangements for Foreign Minister Fumio Kishida to visit Russia for the time being, government sources said.

The move comes after the government felt strong resentment over the Russian prime minister’s visit to Etorofu, one of the four northern territories off Hokkaido.
    <br/><br/>
    <ul>
      <li>Text text kdfjlsdjflksjdflkjsldjfs</li>
        <li>Text text kdfjlsdjflksjdflkjsldjfs</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi can you explain to me what you just did? I see that you have hided //var showChar = 100; and added <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>.

Comment: @Biki Get the value of `showChar` using the position of end of first sentence using `var showChar = content.indexOf(".") + 1;` this is calculated for each time loop executes.

Comment: @Biki He did not include the script tag. I did that to _your_ question (I edited it) to make the code snippet functional. He then copied the code from your question.

Comment: @Biki the `script` tag is for making a demo in this answer itself. that has nothing to do with the real solution. The code changed in the script for calculating the end value is what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But I supposed this will control all the articles content, but not each? For example i want my first article to my one sentence long and then continue with "more". And second article I want it to be 2 sentence and then continue with "more".